# Simple foreach, preferred way

Tags: c#, .net

I'm accessing some values from the list to populate list of strings in this way

```
List<string> carNames = null;
foreach (var car in dal.Cars)
{
    carNames.Add(car.Name);
}
```

Is there more efficient way, yet readable to write this? How would you do it?

Comment: yes, try this `throw new NullReferenceException()`

Comment: Yes, use Linq: `var carNames = dal.Cars.Select(car => car.Name).ToList();` (It's NOT more efficent though, just more readable)

Comment: (If you don't understand Yegor's comment: It's because your sample code should have `List<string> carNames = new();` otherwise `carNames.Add(car.Name)` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.)

Comment: think about it: at _some_ layer, you have to 1) create a list/array/whatever to store your values in, and 2) add each value to your list. there isn't really anything you can do about simplifying the task at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Is there a more efficient way"
```

More efficient is often micro optimization and most times decreases readability. However, one way to optimize performance would be to initialize the list with the correct capacity, which you know already because `dal.Cars` is also a list:

```
List<string> carNames = new List<string>(dal.Cars.Count);
carNames.AddRange(dal.Cars.Select(c => c.Name));
```

Sidenote: i really wonder why microsoft didn't add an overload for `ToList`/`ToArray`/`ToHashSet` which takes the capacity. Then you *could* use this (Does NOT compile):

```
List<string> carNames = dal.Cars.Select(c => c.Name).ToList(dal.Cars.Count);
```

Comment: I doubt we should answer such opinion-based questions, should we?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The "readable" aspect is opinion-based, but the "efficiency" aspect is not, IMHO.